# Find n integers in list that after multiplying equal to m

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I need to print out n indexes of elements of list that after multiplying equal to some given integer. It's guaranteed that the combination exists in  a list. For example, for the following input(number of elements in array, multiplication wanted number, number of elements in wanted sublist and given array):

> 7 60 4 
>  
>   30 1 1 3 10 6 4

I should get in any order

> 1 2 4 5

Because 1*1*10*6==60. If there are more than 1 solution I need to print any of them.
My solution works but pretty slow, how can I make it work faster?

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

arr = list(map(int, input().split()))
numbers = list(map(int, input().split()))

s = sorted(numbers)


def filtered_sublists(input_list, length):
    return (
        l for l in all_sublists(input_list)
        if len(l) == length
    )


def all_sublists(l):
    return chain(*(combinations(l, i) for i in range(len(l) + 1)))


def multiply(arr):
    result = 1
    for x in arr:
        result = result * x
    return result


def get_indexes(data):
    indexes = []

    for i in range(len(data)):
        if arr[1] == multiply(data[i]):
            for el in data[i]:
                if numbers.index(el) in indexes:
                    all_ind = [i for i, x in enumerate(numbers) if x == el]
                    for ind in all_ind:
                        if ind not in indexes:
                            indexes.append(ind)
                            break
                else:
                    indexes.append(numbers.index(el))

            break

    return indexes


sublists = list(filtered_sublists(numbers, arr[2]))

print(*get_indexes(sublists))
```

Comment: @גלעדברקן n,m,k - (1≤K≤N≤5000,0≤M≤10^9), array elements - (0≤Ai≤10^9), unfortunately can't share testing wabpage because it's kind of private task

Answer (score 0):

The key is don't test *every* combination.

```
def combo(l, n=4, target=60, current_indices=[], current_mul=1):
    if current_mul > target and target > 0:
        return
    elif len(current_indices) == n and current_mul == target:
        yield current_indices
        return
    for i, val in enumerate(l):
        if (not current_indices) or (i > current_indices[-1] and val * current_mul <= target):
            yield from combo(l, n, target, current_indices + [i], val * current_mul)

l = [30,1,1,3,10,6,4]
for indices in combo(l, n=4, target=60):
    print(*indices)
```

Prints:

```
1 2 4 5
```

---

More testcases:

```
l = [1,1,1,2,3,3,9]
for c, indices in combo(l, n=4, target=9):
    print(*indices)
```

Prints:

```
0 1 2 6
0 1 4 5
0 2 4 5
1 2 4 5
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works, but I still get time limit error.

Comment: I don't know the inputs but the time limit is 1s, your solution takes 1.091s

Comment: It used to return time limit error on 13th test, now I get "Presentation error" on 11th test, possible reasons "1. Incorrect output format 2. No output at all 3. Extra output"

Comment: @Steve see my edit, I added `*` to print the output. What is this 11th test - what is the input?

Comment: The thing is that tests are hidden and I don't know them, the result must be one array printed with indexes starting from 1, so I print them with `print(*map(lambda x:x+1, indices))` and put `break` at the end of the loop so I get only one solution, which looks like 2 3 5 6

Comment: That's right, but there are some weird input/output criteria so not to spend time explaining it I didn't mention that. Because generally it doesn't matter, I just added +1 to your solution and got the right result. But still there is a problem with time limit with your previous solution.

Comment: Getting "Presentation error" on 11th test again :( Sad that I don't really know what data they use there as an input

Comment: @Steve Now I see where it could be a problem - array elements could contain zero `(0≤Ai≤10^9)`. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a memoized recursion for an `O(n * k * num_factors)`, solution, where `num_factors` depends on how many factors of the target product we can create. The recurrence should be fairly clear from the code. (Zeros aren't handled but those should be pretty simple to add extra handling for.)

Pythonesque JavaScript code:

```js
function f(A, prod, k, i=0, map={}){
  if (i == A.length || k == 0)
    return []

  if (map[[prod, k]])
    return map[[prod, k]]

  if (prod == A[i] && k == 1)
    return [i]

  if (prod % A[i] == 0){
    const factors = f(A, prod / A[i], k - 1, i + 1, map)
    if (factors.length){
      map[[prod, k]] = [i].concat(factors)
      return map[[prod, k]]
    }
  }

  return f(A, prod, k, i + 1, map)
}

var A = [30, 1, 1, 3, 10, 6, 4]

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(A, 60, 4)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(A, 60, 3)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f(A, 60, 1)))
```

Comment: Will try this out tomorrow and return with feedback

Comment: @Steve cool. I amended and simplified the code to not include `i` in the map key.

Answer (score 0):

You could start from the target product and recursively divide by factors in the remaining list until you get down to 1 and after using the specified number of factors.  This has the advantage of quickly eliminating whole branches of recursion under numbers that are not a factor of the target product.

Handling zero values in the list and a target product of zero requires a couple of special conditions at the start and while traversing factors.

For example:

```
def findFactors(product, count, factors, offset=0):
    if product == 0: return sorted((factors.index(0)+i)%len(factors) for i in range(count))  
    if not count: return [] if product == 1 else None
    if not factors: return None
    for i,factor in enumerate(factors,1):
        if factor == 0 or product%factor != 0: continue
        subProd = findFactors(product//factor,count-1,factors[i:],i+offset)
        if subProd is not None: return [i+offset-1]+subProd

r = findFactors(60, 4, [30,1,1,3,10,6,4])
print(r) # [1, 2, 4, 5]

r = findFactors(60, 4, [30,1,1,0,3,10,6,4])
print(r) # [1, 2, 5, 6]

r = findFactors(0, 4, [30,1,1,3,10,6,0,4])
print(r) # [0, 1, 6, 7]
```